# Sum of infinite series leading to conflict

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I tried messing around with pretty basic infinite series sums and it didn't end well. I'm fairly confident that I've made a mistake either in calculations or in the methodology so please help me out. Here's what I did (most of it is pretty common)-
$$P = \sum_{i=0}^n 1/2^i = 2$$
I did something pretty similar-
$$ Q = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac {1}{2^i(-1)^i} = 1 - 1/2 + 1/4 - 1/8 ...$$
$$ 2Q = 2 - 1 + 1/2 - 1/4 + 1/8 ... = 2 - (1 - 1/2 + 1/4 - 1/8 ...) = 2 - Q$$
$$ Q = 2/3 $$
And now, P - Q,
$$ 2 - 2/3 = (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 ...) - (1 - 1/2 + 1/4 - 1/8 ...)$$
$$ 4/3 = (1 - 1) + (1/2 + 1/2) + (1/4 - 1/4) + (1/8 + 1/8) ... $$
$$ 4/3 = 1 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 ... $$
$$ 1/3 = 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 ... = 1/2 (1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 ...)$$
$$ 1/3 = 1/2(P -1) = 1/2 (2 -1) = 1/2$$
And I end up with
$$ 1/3 = 1/2 $$
I apologize for any mistakes I've made.

Comment: the mistake here $1/3 = 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 ... = 1/2 (1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 ...)$

it must be
$$1/3 = 1/4 + 1/16 + 1/64 ... = . ...)$$

Comment: Yes, the geometric series you get for $P-Q$ has common ratio $1/4$, not $1/2$.

Comment: @E.H.E Gee sorry I didn't realize that. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks to you too!